# Meaning of sparse annotation for images?

Tags: image-processing, timeseries-segmentation, labeling

what is sparse annotation? Is it pixel-wise labeling for images. what are the other types of annotation?

Comment: not every pixel is labeled

Comment: so there are some unlabeled pixels that are considered as "don't care"?